# Applying Neuroph to Android Video

Tags: android, frame

Is it possible for Neuroph to recognize each frames of a running Camera instead of just pictures? How?

Neuroph accepts the Image Object for its recognition

```
HashMap<String, Double> output = imageRecognition.recognizeImage(image);
```

This is coming from these imports

```
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin;
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.image.Image;
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.image.ImageFactory;
```

The frames of the camera are in Bitmap format. How do you convert from Bitmap to Image?

Comment: what are `opencv`, `neural-network`, `android-camera` tags doing here?

Comment: I am trying to make an application that recognizes objects in real-time using the camera of an Android phone. The example that Neuroph has in its website is that it browses the Gallery first for an image then recognizes it.

Comment: but the question is not connected with these tags at all - deleted.

Answer (score 2):

First, use latest version of Neuroph which is 2.7.

Then use some of org.neuroph.imgrec.image.ImageFactory.getImage() to get Bitmap as image object.

Image class is used in order to privide same API for Android and J2SE platforms. Image factory determines which paltform its been running on and use coresponding class and wrap it as Image object.

Comment: As what I've understood from the source code of ImageFactory, it accepts the location in terms of URL or String or File of where the image is from the phone.

    public static Image getImage(URL imageUrl) 
    public static Image getImage(File imageFile)
    public static Image getImage(String filePath)

Comment: The Bitmap that I have resides in a variable of type Bitmap (import android.graphics.Bitmap;). It is not saved on the phone memory so I can't use the 3 functions above. The Bitmap is constantly refreshed every cycle so I have no problem with the capturing part.

Is there a way to use this Bitmap immediately instead? like a public static Image getImage(Bitmap bmp) function?